# Powershell: Save file to standing directory

Tags: xml, powershell, directory

I'm trying to save an XML file from a powershell script to the standing directory, but after some reading online it seems the possibility's are limited. Anyone knows some code that saves to 'standing directory' instead of this code that saves to a 'full path':

-This code is run after the XML is made and some variables are saved to the XML.

```
$template | out-File C:\Scripts\XML\info.xml
$systemroot = [System.Environment]::SystemDirectory
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load("C:\Scripts\XML\info.xml")
```

-This code is run at the very end of the script, after the XML and after some commands that adds information to the XML.

```
$xml.Save("/info.xml")
Get-Content /info.xml
```

Alle help is appreciated!

Comment: Am I the only one not know what it means 'standing directory'? could you post some example? thanks

Comment: What I mean is I would like the XML to be saved to the same location as the script, the same file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the Path of your script in this way:

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

Then you can use `$ScriptPath` as path  in your script to load or save xml file:

```
$template | out-File $ScriptPath\info.xml
```